How to create a system for determining whether a player is in the dark or under light?
In my 3D game, I need a system to determine whether the player is standing in complete darkness (returning false) or under a streetlight or any other light source (returning true).
The following options are not suitable as they require too many resources:
Raycasting in a circle and searching for objects with the Light component.
Caching all light sources and checking the distance.
Placing triggers.
What would be an efficient approach to achieve this?
Light sources can be added or removed as the game progresses

"as they require too many resources"... raycasting would be the usual way of doing this. Try rascast from each light to the player and see if that ray is within the light's frustrum, distance, and hits nothing else. Are you saying it takes too many reasources because you've benchmarked it or are you assuming?

@Jay raycasting requires verification via TryGetComponent, which in turn is demanding. You can of course use tags, but I'm looking for an alternative

If you have a very large number of light sources and need blinding performance then i'd suggest an Octree to elimitate distant lights and then raytrace the near ones. But this is almost certainly overkill <1000 lights. I would be very suprised if TryGetComponent was causing performance issues, just how many lights do you have?

im at planning phase so idk, but ill check Octree, thanks!

If your lights are Spot or Point lights, you could have a script in each light that checks its own distance with the player every frame. If the distance is less or equal than the radius of the light then the character is in the light otherwise is not. Unless your character is a single pixel (which I doubt jaja), you will probably have to add a bit of offset to consider the size of the character.

But if I have, say, 200 light sources and each of them checks the distance to the player, this will affect performance

200 is not a big number, try it and benchmark. Are you targeting very old mobile platforms?

for PC, but I want to optimize the game well from the start. But thank you very much, I'll take a look

If you are worried about the performance, which I would test first to see if it is a problem, you could use some sort of grid base (assuming your lights don't move) logic to check distance only against lights in the same grid section as the player.
